# Issue while transfering a yii project from a server to another one (routing issue)

Tags: php, yii, configuration, project, transfer

I'm in charge of transfering a yii project developped by another people, working on a server (A) to another server (B). In the B server a website which must be kept is already running with apache in `/var/www/html/site`

The app is website with a REST API. The link to the website is **www.domain.com/max** (`located in /var/www/html/max`) and the link to the api is : **www.domain.com/max/apiV1** (`located in /var/www/html/max/protected/apiV1` I suppose)..

I tried to copy/paste the folder of the website and access to it : it works but when I try to go on others routes than the default one, it returns a "Not Found" for everything.

Here, an extract of the configuration file :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        'login'=>'site/login',
        'logout'=>'site/logout',
        'about'=>'site/about',
        'how-it-works'=>'site/howitworks',
        'our-offers'=>'site/ouroffers',
        'contact'=>'site/contact',
        'join'=>'site/register', 
        ),
),
```

And a SiteController extract showing that the login route should work, isnt it ?

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
      ...
    }
```

Also, I don't see anything releving to the API (which is a module of the yii project).. So I don't understand how the A server can reach something with the **www.domain.com/apiV1**

---

I would like to be able to request the API's and access to the website fully.

I hope my explaination is explicit enough, don't hesitate to ask for more information on the project !

Thanks for reading!
I really hope we we'll be able to find a solution

EDIT : 
Apache Configuration files

yep

In the A server the apache config "000-default" is :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/max"
   <Directory "/var/www/html/max/">
       # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
       RewriteEngine on
       # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
       RewriteRule . index.php

       # use index.php as index file
       DirectoryIndex index.php

       # ...other settings...
   </Directory>
```

And in the B for the file "max.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/max

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =maxtouch-app.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . index.php
 RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]
```

Edit 2 : .htaccess file of project

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: did you check the previous apache/nginx config?

Comment: `<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',` move them to the end off the list

Comment: Yes I checked them. I edited the question added the apache configuration files @delboy1978uk

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam : Smart idea ! But it does not work

Comment: ok are you able to access the routes without using pretty urls ? using `index.php?r=controller/action`

Comment: Did the application not included a htaccess config?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam : Unfortunatly no.. I still on the same page whatever I write with pretty urls : index.php?r=site/register is same than index.php?r=site/login ..etc

Comment: @SyakurRahman : the application includes a .htaccess file in the main folder ! I added it on my post but it seems ok

Comment: Could you include your modules configuration? It might be something related to the module, since there is nothing both in htaccess and the routes.

Comment: are you using the basic or advance-app? also are you using any user module like `yii2-user` ?

Answer (score -1):

As, you said you can access the default route i.e **www.domain.com/max** but fails to access further routes. The problem could be that your server fails to point a url like **www.domain.com/max/some/other/path** to the **/var/www/html/max** folder. For that your `.htaccess` located at **/var/www/html/** should have a rewrite rule something like this `RewriteRule ^max max/index.php`. Hence your `.htaccess` will look something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# if url has max in the start of path then point to to max folder
RewriteRule ^max max/index.php

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Furthermore in your project configuration you need to add **max/** before all rules to configure urlManager for you project location. It will look something like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'max/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        'max/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        'max/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        'max/login'=>'site/login',
        'max/logout'=>'site/logout',
        'max/about'=>'site/about',
        'max/how-it-works'=>'site/howitworks',
        'max/our-offers'=>'site/ouroffers',
        'max/contact'=>'site/contact',
        'max/join'=>'site/register', 
        ),
),
```

Hope it'll help you.